# Is there any known full device/disk encryption software for android 2.2?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, encryption

I have not found anything in the app store or other stores, Is there any known full device/disk encryption software for android 2.2, that you have test on your device? if so what is the device?

FYI:I know honeycomb supports this natively, but my device does not support HC.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to get it via an app, you'd need it at the ROM level. I doubt anyone has done it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any known rom(s) with full device encryption incorporated?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11120/are-there-any-known-roms-with-full-device-encryption-incorporated)

Answer (score 1):

Full device/disk encryption can only be done correct with OS privileges. That's why there is no such App. But newer Android versions and some ROMs provide this features. Have a look at ["Are there any known rom(s) with full device encryption incorporated?"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11120/are-there-any-known-roms-with-full-device-encryption-incorporated)

Comment: `That's why there is no such app.` ~> You are saying like there's no root app in the world. Apps can do this with root access.