# Are there any known rom(s) with full device encryption incorporated?

Tags: rom, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Are there any recommendable known rom(s) with full device/disk encryption incorporated?

Device specs: Samsung ARM Cortex A8 processor at 1GHz, and 512MB RAM, right now runs Android 2.2.

Answer (score 5):

You mean like [WhisperCore](http://www.whispersys.com/whispercore.html)? Quoting from it's site:

> By default, WhisperCore encrypts your entire data partition at the device level, and can optionally be enabled for your phone's SD card as well. WhisperCore also includes smudge-resistant screen unlock patterns.

Unfortunately it only currently runs on the Nexus handsets.

Comment: thanks, I hope them to get out versions for other devices. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Android doesn't do hardware encryption. Software encryption on the system is also not done. Its really something that they should work on.

For you, I recommend using a combination of thirdparty apps to encrypt the individual sections of your phone such as calls, texts, etc. Its a really not a good solution but the best one at the moment. :(